# how to grant remote access for mysql database from another network?

Tags: remote-access

I am using MAMP, on a Mac.  I have granted access to all ip addresses using:
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* to ‘%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
My team members need to access this database from their homes, meaning they are not on the same network as I am.  I researched how to make a test connection using msql workbench, but that means they have to have it on their computers too, no?  Also, if my database path is obviously on **my** computer, what would the host info be on their new connection setup?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your Mac is sitting at your home behind a router.
The first thing you should do, is open/forward the port(s) that are required to access mysql in your router. The default should be 3306. So any request that comes to your router on this port goes to your Mac. Check your routers manual for this.
Then your colleagues need your current IP (http://whatismyipaddress.com/).

With the IP and port they should be able to create a connection to the mysql server on your Mac.

Once you get this working you can look into the topic of "dynamic dns", to account for changes of you home IP address.

Comment: thank you. I have done the port forwarding and now looking into dynamic dns. this is all so that my team's android application can access the database

Comment: Jane, please be also aware that by default none of the communication between the app (or any device) and mysql is encrypted. Thus you should also take a look at the following thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266493/is-the-standard-mysql-connection-over-port-3306-secure-in-sequel-pro